# Failed to execute MI command (Hexagon SDK)

Tags: eclipse, hexagon-dsp

I am trying to run the calculator example from the Hexagon SDK IDE (Eclipse based) on the snapdragon 820 development kit (AQP8096) on Windows 10 (64bit). I imported both projects: the hexagon common library project "libcalculator_skel" and the android application "calculator", and build them succesfully. I have also set breakpoints in the "calculator_imp.c" file.

When I debug the shared library as an attached hexagon application I get the following error:

Error in final launch sequence

Failed to execute MI command:

-target-select remote localhost:6500

Error message from debugger back end:

Command 'target-select'. Error connecting to target: ''
Command 'target-select'. Error connecting to target: ''

I have also tried with the android application calculator_64 and I get the same error. I have also tried to uncheck the stop on startup option under the debugger options (I read that in a forum). However none of those things work.

If I run the program as an native android app it gives me the output I desire but I want to be able to debug it!

I´ve already read some questions in this forum but they not answer to this specific issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of the Hexagon SDK do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8x96 Targets don't support GDB or LLDB which Eclipse requires as a backend

LLDB support is coming back in 8x98 and newer platforms